# Symfony2 - fosuserbundle - How to limit birthdate in a registration form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, fosuserbundle

Is it possible to automatically validate the date of birth field in a form by limiting the input to the only users older than a certain age?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...
        ->add('birthday', 'date', array(
            'format' => 'dd-MMMM-yyyy',
            'years' =>  range(\date("Y") - 13, \date("Y") - 100),
        ))
        //...
    ;
}
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. you should use [Callback validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

I think `String method name` option described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#methods) would fit your needs.